# Is there a way in rspec to specify a before block for *all* examples in spec_helper.rb?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'd like to run a piece of code before *each* test in my suite (many files, many `describe` blocks). Is there a way to do that, for example, by setting something in the spec_helper.rb file?

I know about `before(:each)`, but my understanding is that that is used within a single `describe` block.

Comment: `before(:suite)` hook?

Comment: Please note the following though: "**WARNING**: Setting instance variables are not supported in `before(:suite)`" So it really depends on what you are going for and why. Also when you say "before *all*" do you mean once or "before *each*". Can you provide a bit more context to the question so others can propose true answers or applicable recommendations? Or maybe just looking through the [Docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-11/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks) can point you in the direction you are looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't `before(:suite)` be executed only once before the suite begins? I need it to execute before each test. Ah, I see my wording was ambiguous...fixing it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically add the following configuration in your spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  # other configs

  config.before(:each) do
    # Do something
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do you say it requires rspec-rails? I don't think it does.

Comment: @KeithBennett you do not. This will work just fine using just rspec. That being said the implementation here is still correct and will provide the desired result.

Comment: BrightMensah, if you correct the Rails part of this I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: @KeithBennett rails part corrected.